# Postman on Ubuntu - cannot insert hidden client certificate

Tags: ssh

I have generated the self-signed client certificate (*.pfx) that is located in Ubuntu (22.04) hidden folder (e.g. ./.ssh/client.pfx). Unfortunately Postman (10.x) does not show any hidden folder and therefore I cannot insert the certificate for a specific site. Maybe someone know whether is there the way to insert client certificate from hidden folder?

Comment: You need to ask the creator of postman not users of Ubuntu -> https://community.postman.com/

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will do it like you said.

Comment: .pfx seems to be a OpenSSL certificate, not a OpenSSH certificate. You would not put those in `.ssh`. For system-wide applications like cURL, you would put them in somewhere inside `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and run `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`. For browsers, you need to use the certificates section of each browser's settings